# image uploader in post free ad page is not working in osclass

Tags: fine-uploader, osclass

I am new to Osclass. I have purchased shopclass theme. we are using jquery fine uploader plugin for image upload. when we are uploading image it shows error.

"[FineUploader 3.8.0] Error when attempting to parse xhr response text (Unexpected token < in JSON at position 61)"-this is the error shown in console.

The image is uploaded into temp folder but it does not shown in post and also shows uploading error in user end.Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Step 1: upgrade to a recent version of Fine Uploader. 3.8 is years old. Step 2: make sure your server is _always_ returning valid JSON.

Comment: To answer the question you posted (as an answer): make sure your server is always returning valid JSON.

Comment: It is work fine in localhost and our company server.It is not worked in client server.json extensions are already enabled in client server.

Comment: Your server is clearly not returning valid JSON in this instance. I suggest you take a closer look at the response in the browser's dev tools.